# Rolling Motion: Rigid body dynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

[image]

> For a body to have pure roll/no slipping, V=Rw = the speed at contact point. Whereas, in this example the speed at contact point B is V=7.5ft/s due to rolling and V=2ft/s due to translating point.What's the problem with my concept?

Comment: $v=r\omega$ is true only when the pure rolling occurs on a non moving surface. It's clearly explained in the book.

Answer (score 1):

$v=R\omega$ is true *with respect to the surface it is rolling on*. Since in addition to the cylinder moving on the surface, the surface itself is also moving, you need to add those velocities to get the speed in the resting reference frame.